# json Deserialize dynamic to convert it to model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, system.text.json

> I'm trying to convert

```
dynamic AdvanceEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(File);
```

to model class that is AdvanceEventsDto

```
 public class AdvanceEventsDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The Event List
        /// </summary>
        public   EventsDto[] Events { get;set;}

        /// <summary>
        /// The Winner
        /// </summary>
        public string Winner { get; set; }
    }
```

and EventDto calss is

```
public class EventsDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Events
        /// </summary>
        public string Events { get; set; }
    }
```

json is

```
{
  "Events" : [
    "France",
    "Netherlands",
    "Argentina",
    "Brazil",
    "France",
    "Argentina",
    "Qatar",
    "Brazil",
    "Germany",
    "Japan",
    "Brazil",
    "Portugal",
    "Japan",
    "Japan",
    "Brazil"
  ],
  "Winner" : "Brazil"
}
```

when i'm trying to get values like follows

```
 string  FilePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\Data\AdvanceEvents.json");
                string  File = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( FilePath);
                dynamic AdvanceEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>( File);
                var events = AdvanceEvent[0];
```

but i'm getting following error
`The requested operation requires an element of type 'Array', but the target element has type 'Object'.`

I'm trying to map AdvanceEvents.json values to class AdvanceEventsDto  and class  EventsDto

Comment: `dynamic` should be a last resort.  You have a wellknown model, so there is absolutely no reason to use dynamic.  If your JSON doesn't match your model, copy your JSON to the clipboard and use Edit/Paste JSON as classes to get a good model.

Comment: now I'm getting "The JSON value could not be converted to xxxx.BasicAuth.Api.Models.EventsDto[]. Path: $.Events[0] | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 12."

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your actual JSON matches that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

fix the class

```
public class AdvanceEventsDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The Event List
        /// </summary>
        public  string[] Events { get;set;}

        /// <summary>
        /// The Winner
        /// </summary>
        public string Winner { get; set; }
    }
```

and use this code

```
AdvanceEventsDto advanceEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AdvanceEventsDto>(File);

string[] events = advanceEvent.Events;
```

Comment: now i'm getting "The JSON value could not be converted to xxxx.BasicAuth.Api.Models.EventsDto[]. Path: $.Events[0] | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 12."

Comment: @NuwanIndika , all my code is tested. Pls check your json string one more time

Comment: json also mention in the question

Comment: `EventsDto` ?   That doesn't match this code - are you sure you have updated `AdvanceEventsDto` to match this answer?